# what is the approach used by BernoulliNB in sklearn package for prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I was reading up on the implementation of naive bayes in Sklearn, and I was not able to understand the predict part of BernoulliNB:

Code borrowed from [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L822)

```
def _joint_log_likelihood(self, X):
    #.. some code ommited

    neg_prob = np.log(1 - np.exp(self.feature_log_prob_))
    # Compute  neg_prob · (1 - X).T  as  ∑neg_prob - X · neg_prob
    jll = safe_sparse_dot(X, (self.feature_log_prob_ - neg_prob).T)
    jll += self.class_log_prior_ + neg_prob.sum(axis=1)

    return jll
```

What is the role of `neg_prob` in this. Can someone explain this approach?

Everywhere I am reading online ([source](https://towardsdatascience.com/spam-classifier-in-python-from-scratch-27a98ddd8e73)) the simple approach is that:

```
For word in document:
    For class in all_class:
        class_prob[class] += np.log(class_prob_for[word])
# basically add up the log probability of word given that class.
# (Which is pre computed from training data)

# finally add up the log probability of the class itself.

For class in all_class:
    class_prob[class] += np.log(class_prob_for[class])
```

But this does not quite give the same result as `BernoulliNB`

Any information is much appreciated. Please let me know if I should add more detail, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `BernoulliNB` is slightly different from `MultinomialNB`.

As explained here: http://blog.datumbox.com/machine-learning-tutorial-the-naive-bayes-text-classifier/

Terms which don't occur within the document are also used as: `(1 - conditional_probability_of_term_in_class)`

> The Bernoulli variation, as described by Manning et al (2008),
>   generates a Boolean indicator about each term of the vocabulary equal
>   to 1 if the term belongs to the examining document and 0 if it does
>   not. The model of this variation is significantly different from
>   Multinomial not only because it does not take into consideration the
>   number of occurrences of each word, but also because it takes into
>   account the non-occurring terms within the document. While in
>   Multinomial model the non-occurring terms are completely ignored, in
>   Bernoulli model they are factored when computing the conditional
>   probabilities and thus the absence of terms is taken into account.

Algo used in sklearn Source: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-bernoulli-model-1.html